# webRTC multi-peer connection

Tags: webrtc

I have successfully connected clients A and B. Problem is I want to add new clients, C and D to build a group chat. 
Do I need to spawn new RTC connection and exchange offer/answer/ICE candidates for each clients? For example:

A connects to B
A connects to C
A connects to D
B connects to C
B connects to D
C connects to D

Each of the above client combination spawns their own RTCPeerConnection and goes through the webrtc handshake (offer,icecandidate,answer)

Comment: Do you have some code? Is very hard to find an example where C can join A and B.

Answer (score 16):

> Do I need to spawn new RTC connection and exchange offer/answer/ICE candidates for each clients?

Exactly. Each client just need to create new `RTCPeerConnection`, attach their unique audio and video tracks to them and exchange their SDP & ICE candidates every time a new client arrives.

An example is available here: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/

Source code: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/multiple/js/main.js

Comment: This is a horrible if I have a large number of peers

Comment: For a group of 25 members, total of 300 connections are needed !! (which is (nCr) = (25 C 2) = 300 see https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/combinations.php )

Comment: Each member will need to connect to each member - so if there are 25 then each member would have 24 connections

Comment: Unless one of the group is the "master", which have 1 single connection to all clients (slave) so you only have 24 connections (master-slave connections). It totally depends on whether you're in a hierarchical structure (master/slave) or "flat" pure peer2peer one (25*24 connections)

Comment: That example uses 3 fixed peers, and just 2 two-ways connections instead of 3. Do you have some example where C can join A and B? Thanks!

Comment: This is why companies are racing to solve this issue. See https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-cloudflare-calls/ and https://www.mux.com/real-time-video